PowerShell and WMI Class reference
I'm trying to create a WMI class property in one class that references a property of an instance in another WMI class, using PowerShell.  I've been having a hard time trying to figure out the correct properties and qualifiers to get it working.
The 'Warranty' property in the $className class references the $classNameElement class.
if (!(Get-CimInstance -Namespace $Namespace -ClassName $classNameElement)){
    
        
    # Create a ManagementClass object bound to the WMI repository
    $managementClass = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass($namespace, [String]::Empty, $null)

    # Specify the new class name
    $managementClass["__CLASS"] = $classNameElement

    # Add 'ID' property as a string and mark it as a key
    $managementClass.Properties.Add("ID", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
    $managementClass.Properties["ID"].Qualifiers.Add("Key", $true)

    # Add 'Name' property as a string
    $managementClass.Properties.Add("Name", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)

    # Add 'Description' property as a string
    $managementClass.Properties.Add("Description", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)

    # Add 'Type' property as a string
    $managementClass.Properties.Add("Type", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)

    # Add 'Start' property as a string
    $managementClass.Properties.Add("Start", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)

    # Add 'End' property as a string
    $managementClass.Properties.Add("End", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)

    # Create the class in the WMI repository
    $managementClass.Put()
}

$managementClass = $null

if (!(Get-CimInstance -Namespace $Namespace -ClassName $className)){
    
    # Create a ManagementClass object bound to the WMI repository
    $managementClass = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass($namespace, [String]::Empty, $null)

    # Specify the new class name
    $managementClass["__CLASS"] = $className

    # Add Association qualifier
    #$managementClass.Qualifiers.Add("Association",$true)

    # Add 'Serial' property as a string and mark it as a key
    $managementClass.Properties.Add("Serial", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)
    $managementClass.Properties["Serial"].Qualifiers.Add("Key", $true)

    # Add 'Country' property as a string
    $managementClass.Properties.Add("Country", [System.Management.CimType]::String, $false)

    # Add 'Warranty' property as a reference to the Device_WarrantyElement class
    $managementClass.Properties.Add("Warranty", [System.Management.CimType]::Reference, $true)

    $managementClass.Properties["Warranty"].Qualifiers.Add("CIMTYPE", "ref:Device_WarrantyElement")

    # Create the class in the WMI repository
    $managementClass.Put()


}


You might try to use this ObjectGraphTools set to explore the object: [System.Management.ManagementClass]::new() | ConvertTo-Expression -LanguageMode Full -HighFidelity.

Can you tell us more about the hard times you're having? Do you receive an error while creating the new type? Or when creating instances of the new type? If the latter: show us the code you use to attempt instantiation. In any case: share the full error messages :)
